# Limit 'contributers' abilities in WordPress

Tags: php, admin

I have a few custom post types which i don't want any contribute to view or touch. However, the default settings allows contributes to see these in their admin. How do i disallow contributes access to certain post types?

Comment: belongs on wordpress.se

Comment: Not going to help? Just click 'close'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your post type you can show/hide the UI in the arguments. I would approach it this way:

```
$allowed = current_user_can('administrator') ? true : false;
$args = array(
    //other args
    'show_ui' => $allowed
);
//register_post_type() function;
```

This will maintain the custom post type architecture while hiding the UI for those who are not administrators. For more information about Wordpress User Capabilities see this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities